# Как сделать проверку radiobutton в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер. Есть  2 радиобаттона, как сделать проверку с помощью if, что выбран первый?

```
<input type="radio" name="r" value=l>1<br> 
<input type="radio" name="r" value=2>2<br>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

функция `check` проверяет на чистом JS без каких-либо библиотек, а функция `check2` с использованием jQuery

```
function check()
{
    var inp = document.getElementsByName('r');
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
        if (inp[i].type == "radio" && inp[i].checked) {
            alert("selected: " + inp[i].value);
        }
    }
}

function check2(){
    alert("selected: " + $('input[name=r]:checked').val());
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/k9DCB/1/)

Answer (score 3):

```js
/**
 * функция isCheck возвращает выбранный элемент на чистом JS без каких-либо библиотек
 * @param name 
 * @returns {Element}
 */
function isCheck(name) {
    return document.querySelector('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked');
}

// пример использования:

alert(isCheck('r').id);
```

```html
<div>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="one">первый
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="two" checked>второй
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, дополните примером испольования функции.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="radio" name="r" value="l" onchange="check()">1<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="r" value="2" onchange="check()">2<br/>
<script>
 function check(){
  var rarr=document.getElementsByName("r");
  if(rarr[0].checked){
    //То выбран первый radio
  }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaScript
let form = document.querySelector('.formValid');
let gender = document.getElementsByName('gender');
(form.gender.value !== 'on') ? console.log('not chek') : console.log('chek');
```

html

```
<form class="formValid">
    <div>
    <div>
         <label>Gender*</label>
    </div>
         <div>
              Female<input type="radio" name="gender">
              Male<input type="radio" name="gender">
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```