# Изменить фон картинки при выборе ее опции по onclick (через CSS)

Tags: javascript, css

Суть в том что есть картинка с прозрачным фоном. 
В опциях картинки есть выбор ее цвета. 
При выборе цвета, картинка должна заливаться соответственно им.
На автомате стоит черный, далее уже по желанию пользователя, чтобы он визуально представлял что будет и в каком цвете.

Меток около 10 и соответственно могут меняться или добавляться со временем.

Задача что при выборе метки (опции), менялся background-color картинки.

```
<img class="test" id="det_img_25959497f734a78c_1434" src="123.png" alt="" title=""  style="">

<label id="option_description_259_1_5" class="ty-product-options__box option-items" style=""><input type="radio" class="radio" name="product_data[259][product_options][1]" value="5" checked="checked" onclick="fn_change_options('259', '1', '5');">Чёрный&nbsp;</label>
<label id="option_description_259_1_3" class="ty-product-options__box option-items" style=""><input type="radio" class="radio" name="product_data[259][product_options][1]" value="3" onclick="fn_change_options('259', '1', '3');">Бежевый&nbsp;</label>
```

Comment: что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: с JS вообще не работал... уже 2ые сутки пытаюсь разобраться с кодом. Хотя понимаю что тут на 30 минут работы ))

Comment: Как я понимаю мне жестко нужно привязать Label ID к определенному цвету, и выводить ее в CSS для нужного IMG class.

Comment: Писать за других тут не принято) вам нужно просто  узнать какая радикнопка нажата - тут ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/110335/Как-сделать-проверку-radiobutton-в-javascript, как вариант можно к каждой добавить атрибут data-bgcolor, взять этот атрибут у нажатой кнопки и записать в bgcolor картинки. (Что то вроде $(#ид_картинки).css('backgroundColor', переменная в которую вытащите дата атрибут)

Comment: <script>
   $(document).ready(function fn_change_options() {
  $('#option_description_259_1_5').click(function fn_change_options() {
          $("image.style.test").css('backgroundColor', 'black');
  });
});

Comment: Выше в посте не работает... хотя на мой взгляд вроде все верно) хотел попробовать прописать на 1-2 опции через жесткую привязку. В итоге получилось бы около 10 опций. Но понимаю что это уж очень коряво.

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен что понял что именно нужно, но вот:

```js
let img = document.querySelector('#img');

document.querySelector('#wrapper').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.nodeName === 'INPUT')
    changeColor.call(e.target);
});

function changeColor(){
  let color = this.dataset.color;
  
  img.style.background = color;
}
```

```css
#img{
  width: 80%;
}
#wrapper input{
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15pt;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#wrapper input:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<img src='http://www.seomofo.com/downloads/new-google-logo-knockoff.png' id='img' /><br /><br />
<div id='wrapper'>
  <input type='button' data-color='#f00' value='Red' />
  <input type='button' data-color='#0f0' value='Green' />
  <input type='button' data-color='#00f' value='Blue' />
</div>
```

Comment: Суть поняли правильно. Спасибо, пошел тестировать.
Попозже отпишусь.

Comment: Вроде все работает... только не понимаю, как мне к моим input или onclick добавить data-color по условию, если совпадают все 3 их параметра, и назначить цвет.

Comment: или еще по ID может проще.

Comment: @Василий, какие параметры, как совпадают и что не понимаете?

Answer (score 0):

пришел пока к такому варианту... В [фидле](https://jsfiddle.net/hrt9bva4/1/) работает, на сайте нет. Цвета перепутал) 2 раза тыкнуть надо

```
let img = document.querySelector('.ty-pict');

document.querySelector('#option_description_259_1_5').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector(".ty-pict").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
};
document.querySelector('#option_description_259_1_1').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector(".ty-pict").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
};
```