# Ошибка document.getElementByName is not function

Tags: javascript, html, css

При работе с radiobutton возникла такая ошибка: document.getElementByName is not function. Как это исправить? Ниже есть строка кода, в которой и наблюдается эта ошибка. Полный код внизу.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> <input type="radio" name="prim" value="груши">Яблоки</p>
<p> <input type="radio" name="prim" value="груши">Груши</p>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var radio = document.getElementByName('prim');

for (var i=0; i<radio.length; i++) {
    radio[i].onchange = testRadio;
}

function testRadio() {
    console.log (this.value);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Да, такой функции на самом деле нет и никогда в браузерах не было

Comment: Есть `getElementsByName`, нету `getElementByName`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать проверку radiobutton в javascript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/110335/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-radiobutton-%d0%b2-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> <input type="radio" name="prim" value="Груши">Яблоки</p>
<p> <input type="radio" name="prim" value="Груши">Груши</p>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var radio = document.getElementsByName("prim");
    for (let i=0; i<radio.length; i++) {
    radio[i].onchange = testRadio;
    }

    function testRadio() {
    console.log (this.value);
    }
</script>
```

Надо было getElementsByName, а не getElementName